# Is there a word like applicality?

Tags: word-usage, errors

I have seen the word *applicality* being used at some places but couldn’t find its meaning when I looked it up on the internet. Example usage:

> But because law doesn’t exist doesn’t mean it can’t be argued in court of the *applicality* of new technology and intent of previous laws.[¹](http://www.amazon.com/forum/amazon%20video%20on%20demand?asin=B000HKW7E0&cdForum=Fx3EQAX98ED5WQ3&cdPage=7&cdThread=TxDZQT97JE54AZ)

Is there really a word like that? If yes, in what context do we use it and how is it different from the work *applicability*?

Comment: What's wrong with *applicability*? It is the noun formed from [applicable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/applicability).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with applicability. I want to know if there a word like applicality exists because I have seen it being used at some places.

Comment: I suspect that the writer is not skilled. "...argued in court of the..." isn't right, which casts doubt on *applicality* anyway. When giving a citation of this type, it's best to include a link in order that the entire context can be considered.

Comment: What @Andrew said. [Here's](http://www.amazon.com/forum/amazon%20video%20on%20demand?asin=B000HEBCZQ&cdForum=Fx3EQAX98ED5WQ3&cdPage=7&cdThread=TxDZQT97JE54AZ) the original of OP's example. But even from the sentence cited, it's clear the writer is *not* a competent English speaker, so I think this is Too Localised.

Comment: Or, if competent, then certainly not careful. In such fora, care in writing tends to be of lower importance than arguing one's point. I'm content this is Too Localised unless it can be shown not to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any mentions of *applicality* are very likely typos of *applicability*.  Even Wiktionary doesn't list the former word, so I highly doubt it's accepted by almost anyone.